# Identify out signal from in signal and impulse response

Tags: discrete-signals, convolution, linear-systems, z-transform

Hi there I am studying a course in signal processing and systems.
I was given an excecise which I am having a great deal of trouble solving.
I am allowed to solved using matlab, but for top marks I must also be able to give an account of a analytical solution.

The task:

Given the in signal $x(n)=(0,4)^nu(n)$

And the impulse response $h(n)=(0,8)^ncos(\dfrac{\pi n}{3})$

compare the plots blow and select the correct alternative:
[image]

Since i needed to give an account of a analytical solution for top marks i decided to try and use z-transformations to solve this.
My thinking was to use the fact that the out signal $Y(z)=X(z)H(z)$, and thus transform the insignal and the impulse response do the multiplication and then transform the results back.

$X(z)=\dfrac{1}{1-0,4z^{-1}}$

and

$H(z)=\dfrac{1-0,8cos(\pi/3)z^{-1}}{1-2z^{-1}0,8cos(\pi/3)+(0,8)^2z^{-2}}=\dfrac{1-0,4z^{-1}}{1-0,8z^{-1}(0.8)^2z^{-2}}$

Which gives $Y(z)=\dfrac{1}{1-0,8z^{-1}(0.8)^2z^{-2}}$

This I have no clue how to transform back, so i decided to let Matlab do the heavy lifting

```
f=cos(pi*n/3)*(0.8)^n
a=ztrans(f)
F=(0.4)^n
b=ztrans(F)
c=a*b
g=iztrans(c)
```

Which gave me the output:

a =(5*z*((5*z)/4 - 1/2))/(4*((25*z^2)/16 - (5*z)/4 + 1))

b =z/(z - 2/5)

c =(5*z^2*((5*z)/4 - 1/2))/(4*(z - 2/5)*((25*z^2)/16 - (5*z)/4 + 1))

g =((-1)^n*3^(1/2)*25^(1 - n)*(- 10 - 3^(1/2)*10i)^(n - 1)*4i)/15 - ((-1)^n*3^(1/2)*25^(1 - n)*(- 10 + 3^(1/2)*10i)^(n - 1)*4i)/15 + (2*(-1)^n*16^n*cos((2*pi*n)/3))/20^n

I have worked on this problem for about a week and can't figure it out. If i am supposed to be able to compare a function with th graph and select the correct one the function have to be fairly simple. The answer sheet sasy the correct grach is A. Feels like I overcomplicate this somewhere.
Help me, please and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to work in the time domain. The output $y[n]$ is given by the convolution of $x[n]$ and $h[n]$:

$$\begin{align}y[n]&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x[n-k]h[k]\\&=u[n]\sum_{k=0}^n(0.4)^{n-k}(0.8)^k\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{3}\right)\\&=u[n](0.4)^n\sum_{k=0}^n2^k\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{3}\right)\tag{1}\end{align}$$

It's clear that the first sample of the output signal is just the multiplication of $x[0]$ and $h[0]$, i.e., $y[0]=x[0]h[0]=1\cdot 1=1$. These leaves us with options $A$ and $C$. Looking at the second output sample

$$y[1]=x[0]h[1]+x[1]h[0]=h[1]+x[1]=0.8\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+0.4=0.8\tag{2}$$

reveals that it must be option $A$.

A closed-form expression for $y[n]$ can be derived from $(1)$ by splitting the cosine into two complex exponentials, and using the formula for the geometric series.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I tried to use convolution but used h(n-k) and got stuck again. You really cleared this up for me, thanks again!